# Why is this column in Pompeii constructed in two parts?

Tags: ancient-rome, architecture

I found columns like this in Pompeii

[image]

The top and bottom are constructed from different materials, and in not quite the same shape.

What happened here? Has it been partially reconstructed? Is this a particular architectural style?

Comment: Maybe recycled building materials, as in the [Basilica cistern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_Cistern) in Constantinople?

Comment: It's a single column. A picture of the building showing more than one column would help.

Comment: @Jan - Any way one may look at it, that mismatch of flutes, although we may lack sufficient details to *explain* it, can hardly be *described* as other than recycling of previous material. That is indeed specific to that column and do not apply to my answer, which is focused on answering what is asked in title. But I have edited it to adjust to your comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Short answer:

- Why two parts: such columns were common.
- Why parts of different form and color: that might reflect (as said in @Jan's comment) the recycling of building material during the construction or restoration of a relatively modest building.

---

### Longer answer:

Considering the question title, the OP seems to think that multi-part columns were unusual; but they were not. Consider the culmination and model of that art, the Parthenon:

[image]

[image: On the Acropolis this technique is dominant]

More [here](https://www.ysma.gr/en/educational-actions/lets-learn-play-and-create/greek-columns-and-column-capitals/).

> Is it made of one or more pieces?
>
> The body of the columns is made of more than one piece, named “drums”
> (or “spondyloi”). Sometimes the column body may consist of one unique
> piece of stone, like the columns of the Athena Nike Temple.
>
> Nowadays, during the restoration works that take place at the
> Acropolis monuments, the ancient and damaged columns are usually
> completed with drums made of new marble.

The column in your picture might very well bear the sign of restoration and/or recycling of material. (I guess the mismatch in color and form of flutes cannot be described otherwise than recycling.)

The less wealthy and prestigious a building, the less harmony in the detail and the technique of combining the parts, something which could explain the fact that the two parts of the column in the question's image (seemingly of a relatively modest or at least not very rich private house) have even different color and texture. But the above images are of the most prestigious kind.

*One-body (monolithic) columns were the exception.*

Wikipedia has an article on [monolithic columns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolithic_column) saying:

> Smaller columns are very often made from single pieces of stone, but
> are less often described as monolithic, as the term is normally
> reserved for less common, larger columns made in this way. Choosing to
> use monolithic columns produces considerable extra difficulties in
> quarrying and transport, and may be seen as a statement of grandeur
> and importance in a building.

An example as such statement is the [Pantheon in Rome](http://omeka.wellesley.edu/piranesi-rome/exhibits/show/pantheon/architecture/architecture-2), which displays sixteen, monolithic exterior columns. But in the interior there are columns made of multiple parts:

[image]

Looking for some other examples with this feature, we find the most important Roman temples of all:

The Temple of Augustus and Livia, Vienne, France

[image]

Maison Carrée in Nîmes, France:

[image]

Temple of Augustus of Pula, Croatia:

[image]

Temple of Bacchus in Baalbek, Lebanon:

[image]

Garni Temple, Armenia:

[image]

As for Greek temples, there is no surprise that the same trend is dominant. I'll not add more pictures (which can be easily found on the internet), but one could mention the most important monuments (beside the aforementioned Acropolis complex): Temple of Olympian Zeus in Athens, Temple of Poseidon at Sounion, Temple of Apollo Epicurius at Bassae, the Doric Temple of Segesta, the Temple of Hera at Paestum, Italy, Temple of Concordia - Agrigento, Italy, beside many others.

---

So, Greek/classical marble columns were made of parts, much like our ...vertebral *column*, because σπόνδυλος (spondylos) mainly means *vertebra* (whence the name of the malady *spondylosis*).

Comment: Many Roman columns were monolithic and unfluted.  You shouldn't assume that all ancient Graeco-Roman architecture was the same.

Comment: @MAGolding - Not assuming anything like that, it's just that the Pompeii column under discussion *is* made of multiple parts - which one could say it's ["not uncommon"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not_uncommon) (`having an abundance situated between common and uncommon.`) - Or is it  in fact `common`? Just to give it a try, googling for top ten Roman temples, then for top 10 Greek ones, most if not all do feature multi-part columns.

Comment: You bave provided lots of images with matching column sections, but the [flutes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluting_(architecture)) and the material in those two.sections from the OP's image do not seem very well-matched at all (the number of flutes js compatible, but that's all)

Comment: @Jan - The main question (title) *is*  `why 2-parts?`. The OP seems to ask the question based on a main assumption that monolithic columns were the norm. That has to be addressed first. But I have also addressed the part about the really clumsy aspect of that seemingly cheap column: `The less wealthy and prestigious a building, the less harmony in the detail and the technique of combining the parts`. - That might very well be the result of restoration and/or recycling.